# What is "( set -o posix ; set ) | less " doing?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, subshell, set

On my search for a command to list all shell variables, I somehow realized, that there is a command to list all environment variables, but somehow there is no one to list all shell variables, for reasons unknown to me.

However, someone here gave an answer on how to display all variables, shell and environment ones.

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | less
```

He actually did not explain for the layman what this expression does, and my fragmentary understanding is not enough to grasp the idea behind it.

This is what I know:

- **( command1; command2)** this causes the commands to be executed inside a child process of the shell.
- **set** is some way to declare variables, though do not know what the **-o posix** means and why a second **set** is executed in succession
- **command | less** This one is not the problem, even I understand it, it is a pager for more control about the output.

Comment: Full answer is here by the way - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`set` shows all shell variables (exported or not). In Bash, `set -o posix` sets the shell in [POSIX compatibility mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode). (I don't know if other shells have similar syntax for the similar feature, but I'll assume Bash here.)

The difference in this case is that usually Bash's `set` shows also shell functions, but in POSIX mode `set` only shows variables, and changes the output format slightly:

> 44. When the set builtin is invoked without options, it does not display shell function names and definitions.
> 45. When the set builtin is invoked without options, it displays variable values without quotes, unless they contain shell metacharacters, even if the result contains nonprinting characters.

In Bash, there's additionally the [`declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins) that can be used to show all the otherwise hidden or Bash-specific flags of variables: `declare -p xx` shows variable `xx` in a format that Bash can take as input. `declare -p` shows all variables and `declare -f` can be used to show functions.

Comment: So, the gnu/linux whizzkids were some kind of lying to me. there is a simple command to list all shell variables: set. but it lists additionally shell functions.

Comment: with printenv i saw only lines that looked like variables, does this mean printenv only shows environment variables and no environment functions or does something like environment functions not exist at all?

Comment: @sharkant, there's a command called `printenv` in GNU coreutils and (like `env`) as an external program, it can only show variables exported to the environment, not those internal to the shell. I think `(t)csh` also has a built-in `printenv` but that also seems to only show environment variables.

Comment: @sharkant, also, at least Bash _can_ export [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) to subshells, of course it does so by encoding them in environment variables. There's `export -f` to enable exporting a function. That feature was the source of an infamous security vulnerability a while back.

Answer (score 7):

There's two things going on basically: the `set` commands are being called in subshell to avoid messing up your current shell options, and that subshell is being set to POSIX mode before listing all the variables. To quote the manual:

> posix   Change  the behavior of bash where the default operation
>           differs from the POSIX standard
>           to match the standard (posix mode).  See SEE ALSO below for a 
>           reference  to  a  document
>           that details how posix mode affects bash's behavior.

In short, `bash` in POSIX mode will behave closer to what `sh` does.

As for option-less `set`, it's also in the manual and it actually states the *reason* why POSIX mode is necessary:

> set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...] Without options,
>   the name and value of each shell variable are displayed in a format
>   that can be  reused as input for setting or resetting the
>   currently-set variables. . .**In posix mode, only shell variables are listed.**

...as opposed to variables and function definitions, which is what's done when`bash` is in regular mode.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/766312/295286) for more info about POSIX mode.